# How to get class name using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

It's general equery I wounder how to get value from class. My code doesn't work and I don't know why...

HTML

```
<div class="left_100_15">
Example
</div>
<p id="test">

</p>
```

CSS

```
.left_100_15{
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var myVar = setInterval(function() { className() }, 100);

function className() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0].getAttribute("class"); 
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
}
```

What would I like to achieve?

1. I would like to read value(name) from class.
2. Need names for all classes because i need to train JavaScript to become next It Einstein.

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/a35je6px/36/)

Comment: see element.className: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0]` most likely returns the `html` tag. Thres no class on that

Comment: You're getting a list of all elements, then getting the first one from the list, without regard to what that element is or whether it *has* a `class` attribute.

Comment: you are trying to get the class from all elements? or from a specific element?

Comment: For all elements. I will use for statement after I will get for that specific one. That why I need to make test on all elements. Getting value for 1st one.

Comment: @PiotrMirosz then read my answer please

Comment: just a simple console of document.getElementsByTagName("*") would have sufficed to tell you what going wrong. And then it would have been a more specific question instead of, "my code don't work"

Comment: i don't care if i get down voted or no. I get answer that i was looking for. And that's matter. If someone down voted my question he should at least say why?!  because I'm not pro. Because I'm new. Because I would like to learn. And most important i will become next It Einstein!! but i need to know where i make mistake...

Answer (score 1):

If you need all elements, but get just the first one (don't no why, but...) this code will get all elements in your page and then get the first one. 

Use `className` to get the entire element class(es).

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function() { className() }, 1000);

function className() {
    var x = document.body.children[0];   //this is returning the first of all elements that you have in your document body      
    var fisrtClass = x.className
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = fisrtClass;
}
```

```css
.left_100_15{
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_100_15">
Example
</div>
<p class="left_100">
Example 2
</p>
<span class="left_15">
Example 3
</span>
<p id="test">

</p>
```

If you need, for some reason, edit or get a value/attribute from ALL elements, not just the first one, remove the `[0]` and then you will have a collection with all elements, just loop (with `for`) to get each one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need, if not, let me know ;)

```js
// Be sure the code don't run before the DOM is fully loaded
     window.onload = function(){
      function className(){
       /* This is a mistake. You are trying to get the class from the HTML tag
       var x = document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0].getAttribute("class");*/

       //if we log the next line in the console you will see it
       console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0]);

       // The best way to achieve what you want is using id's
      }
      className();

      // Now we will go to the answer (I think you want to return the classes as an array)
      function getClasses(elem){// << I'm sending the main element as a parameter
       var classes = [];
       for(var i=0,j=elem.children.length;i<j;i++){
        classes[i] = elem.children[i].getAttribute('class');
       }
       return classes;
      }
      // Now just call the function sending the element from where you want to search classes
      var abc = getClasses(document.getElementById('elem'));
      var firstClass = abc[0];
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = firstClass;
      console.log(abc);
     }
```

```css
    .left_100_15{
      font-size: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="elem" class="ola buen dia">
  <div class="firstClass wuuuu juuu"></div>
  <div class="firstClass testing"></div>
  <div class="firstClass testClass thirdClass"></div>
</div>
<p id="test">

</p>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var x= parseInt(document.getElimentByClassName("name of the class").value);
```

This I use to get into her value I hope this will give you some idea how getelimentbyclassname work..

Comment: There's no function `getElimentByClassName`. It's `getElementsByClassName`, and it returns a collection, so you have to index it.

Comment: He wants to get the class, not the value. He doesn't know the class, so how can he use `getElementsByClassName`?